# What do Repair and Compact operations do to an .MDB? Will they stop an application crashing?

Tags: ms-access, crash

What do Repair and Compact operations do to an `.MDB`?

If these operations do not stop a 1GB+ `.MDB` backed VB application crashing, what other options are there?

Why would a large sized `.MDB` file cause an application to crash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"What do compact and repair operations do to an MDB?"

First off, don't worry about repair. The fact that there are still commands that purport to do a standalone repair is a legacy of the old days. That behavior of that command was changed greatly starting with Jet 3.51, and has remained so since that. That is, a repair will never be performed unless Jet/ACE determines that it is necessary. When you do a compact, it will test whether a repair is needed and perform it before the compact.

So, what does it do?

A compact/repair rewrites the data file, elmininating any unused data pages, writing tables and indexes in contiguous data pages and flagging all saved QueryDefs for re-compilation the next time they are run. It also updates certain metadata for the tables, and other metadata and internal structures in the header of the file.

All databases have some form of "compact" operation because they are optimized for performance. Disk space is cheap, so instead of writing things in to use storage efficiently, they instead write to the first available space. Thus, in Jet/ACE, if you update a record, the record is written to the original data page only if the new data fits within the original data page. If not, the original data page is marked unused and the record is rewritten to an entirely new data page. Thus, the file can become internally fragmented, with used and unused data pages mixed in throughout the file.

A compact organizes everything neatly and gets rid of all the slack space. It also rewrites data tables in primary key order (Jet/ACE clusters on the PK, but that's the only index you can cluster on). Indexes are also rewritten at that point, since over time those become fragmented with use, also.

Compact is an operation that should be part of regular maintenance of any Jet/ACE file, but you shouldn't have to do it often. If you're experiencing regular significant bloat, then it suggests that you may be mis-using your back-end database by storing/deleting temporary data. If your app adds records and deletes them as part of its regular operations, then you have a design problem that's going to make your data file bloat regularly.

To fix that error, move the temp tables to a different standalone MDB/ACCDB so that the churn won't cause your main data file to bloat.

On another note not applicable in this context, front ends bload in different ways because of the nature of what's stored in them. Since this question is about an MDB/ACCDB used from VB, I'll not go into details, but suffice it to say that compacting a front end is something that's necessary during development, but only very seldom in production use. The only reason to compact a production front end is to update metadata and recompile queries stored in it.

Comment: and if you use a SQL Server backend, this step is just a complete waste of time then?

Comment: Yes, if SQL Server is used on the back end, just about nothing will happen to your database on a compact operation.

Answer (score 1):

It's always been that MDB files become slow and prone to corruption as they get over 1GB, but I've never known why - it's always been just a fact of life. I did some quick searching, I can't find any official, or even well-informed insider, explanations of why this size is correlated with MDB problems, but my experience has always been that MDB files become incredibly unreliable as you approach and exceed 1GB.

Here's the MS KB article about Repair and Compact, detailing what happens during that operation:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209769/EN-US/

The app probably crashes as the result of improper/unexpected data returned from a database query to an MDB that large - what error in particular do you get when your application crashes? Perhaps there's a way to catch the error and deal with it instead of just crashing the application.

Comment: I've never seen a MDB/ACCDB file over 1GB, so can't say if they get slow beyond what would be expected linearly for the larger amount of data. Any app of mine that was approaching that amount of data would be on the fast track for upsizing to SQL Server, in any event. It's just too easy for something to bloat a 1GB back end and hit the 2GB limit and then you're just hosed.

Answer (score 1):

If it is crashing a lot then you might want to try a decompile on the DB and/or making a new database and copying all the objects over to the new container.

Try the decompile first, to do that just add the /decompile flag to the startup options of your DB for example

“C:\Program Files\access\access.mdb” “C:\mydb.mdb” /decompile

Then compact, compile and then compact again

EDIT:

You cant do it without access being installed but if it is just storing data then a decompile will not do you any good. You can however look at jetcomp to help you with you compacting needs

support.microsoft.com/kb/273956

Comment: Can I do this without having Access installed?  The .mdb is being used as back-end to a VB app.

Comment: Decompile is irrelevant to a database that has only data tables in it. The question says that its being used from VB, so that makes it crystal clear that decompile is completely non-operative. It won't hurt anything, but it won't help anything, either.

Comment: @David, which is what I said in my edit once I worked out that we were only stroing data